# Manual Formula to Arrayformula Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have been dragging these formulas to end of the Google sheets which makes the sheet to much Heavier and that disturb to much while working to load/perform the action.

I am trying to convert these formulas into Array.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Sheet Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgVGJxkw39uelgPU9ceZLXflnP8KaFGou4rJfSsfVXc/edit#gid=0

```
=IF(AND(E3<>"",B3<>""),EDATE(E3,6),"")

=IF(F3="Confirmed","13",IF(F3="Probation","0",IF(F3="Terminate","",IF(F3="",""))))

=IF(F2="Confirmed",IFERROR(IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=1,12,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=2,11,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=3,10,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=4,9,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=5,8,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=6,7,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=7,6,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=8,5,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=9,4,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=10,3,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=11,2,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G2,"mmm")&" 1"))=12,1))))))))))))*13/12),IF(F2="Probation","0",""))

=IF(F2<>"",K2+IF(I2=0,H2-L2,I2-L2),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following four formulas should work for you.

**Formula #1**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((E3:E<>"")*(B3:B<>""),EDATE(E3:E,6),""))
```

**Formula #2**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS(F3:F="Confirmed","13",F3:F="Probation",0,F3:F="Terminate","",F3:F="",""))
```

**Formula #3**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F3:F="Confirmed",
  IFERROR(IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=1,12,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=2,11,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=3,10,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=4,9,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=5,8,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=6,7,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=7,6,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=8,5,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=9,4,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=10,3,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=11,2,
          IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))=12,1))))))))))))*13/12),
  IF(F3:F="Probation",0,"")))
```

**Formula #4**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F3:F<>"",O3:O+IF(K3:K=0,I3:I-P3:P,K3:K-P3:P),""))
```

**UPDATE:**
Try the following formula to calculate the months of allocated leave, replacing the third formula above:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(G3:G),
                (13 - MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))) * 13/12,
                ""))
```

**UPDATE#2**
Corrected the above formula to add back two criteria checks, which I'd omitted.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(G4:G),
   IF(F4:F="Confirmed",
     (13 - MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G4:G,"mmm")&" 1"))) * 13/12,
     IF(F4:F="Probation",0,0)),""))
```

Note that the last IF test could be eliminated, and replaced with simply "0", but perhaps you want it there for future reference.  I also changed the "0" to just a numeric 0, in all of the formulas.

Comment: kirkg13, Sir thank you so much, There are three more please look into these as well in sheet, Sir i would really appreciate if you can do this. There are three more in sheet please improve them too if possible.

Comment: Sir @kirkg13, thank you, but there is issue if you see attached sheet Col"I" where Col"G" and "F" starts empty there formula show "False". If you can please check it. It should be empty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Leaves During Probation excluding "C" values:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/(1/(IF(B3:B="",,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(Jan!A3:A), {ROW(Jan!A3:A), Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AE, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AF, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AF, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AF, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AF, Dec!C3:AG}, 
 IF(1=SPLIT(REPT("01", DATE(YEAR(E3:E), MONTH(E3:E)+6, DAY(E3:E))-("01/01/2020"-1)), 0), COLUMN(B:AAA), )*1, 0))<>"C", 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(Jan!A3:A), {ROW(Jan!A3:A), Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AE, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AF, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AF, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AF, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AF, Dec!C3:AG}, 
 IF(1=SPLIT(REPT("01", DATE(YEAR(E3:E), MONTH(E3:E)+6, DAY(E3:E))-("01/01/2020"-1)), 0), COLUMN(B:AAA), )*1, 0)), )),,9^9))), " ", )))))))
```

### Compensated Leaves:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/(1/(IF(B3:B="",,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(
 {Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AG, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AG, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AG, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AG, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AG, Dec!C3:AG}="C", 
 {Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AG, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AG, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AG, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AG, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AG, Dec!C3:AG}, )),,9^9))), " ", )))))))
```

### Total Leaves taken This Year no matter the probation

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/(1/(IF(B3:B="",,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( 
 {Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AG, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AG, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AG, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AG, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AG, Dec!C3:AG}),,9^9))), " ", )))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help you provided. @player0, I understand you did correct but how to minus the Col"J" and Col"K" from Col"L" beacuse after subtracting  Col"J" and Col"K" then Col"L" have accurate result.

Comment: And I want mention "0" if result is empty till Col"E" used range after that it will be empty

Comment: Sir, In above sheet highlighted "K9" should be .0
Because he did not take leave during Sep to Dec and his leave 1 is updated ?
I think formula is calculating upon the months not exact year. That is creating an issue.

Comment: Should i post new question @player0